# Python3.5 send object over socket (Pygame cam image)

Tags: python, sockets, camera, pygame, python-3.5

I want to send a PyGame Image over socket with Python 3.5 and i always got a bug.

I get the image, i pickle it, and then i send it.

In the client, i receive it, i unpickle it, and i show it.

But i've got an error :

`fenetre.blit(img, (20, 30))
pygame.error: display Surface quit`

Here is my code for the server ( the one wich send image ) :

```
pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0", (680, 480))
cam.start()
class Streaming(Thread):


    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):

        s = socket.socket()
        s.bind(('192.168.1.158', 12801))
        s.listen(1)
        while True:
            sc, info = s.accept()
            print("Video client connected : "+str(info))
            try:
                while True:
                    image = cam.get_image()
                    str_img = pickle.dumps(image)
                    sc.send(str_img)
                    print(str_img)
                    print("Sending Image")
                    time.sleep(0.005)
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))
```

And the code for the client :

```
fenetre = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 900))
class Receiving(Thread):


    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def run(self):
        global fenetre
        si = socket.socket()
        si.connect(("192.168.1.158", 12801))
        while True:
            img = si.recv(4096)
            img = pickle.loads(img)
            fenetre.blit(img, (20, 30))
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(60)
```

Thank in advance !

Comment: You sends `680x480` = `326400` bytes (or even  `326400 * 3` if pixel uses 3 bytes) but you receive only `4096`. You have to receive all data before you can use `pickle` and `blit`.

Comment: Thank. But now, the problem is that i can't receive a large amount of data in a single `recv` no ? How can i do to receilve 326400 bytes ?

Comment: you have to use loop to receive `4096` bytes many times. If you know how many bytes will be send then you know how many times you have to receive `4096` bytes.

Comment: if you don't know how many bytes receive then you can first send information (with conststant size) how many bytes will be send. then you know that first you have to receive information (with conststant size) and then you will know how many bytes will be send. This way you build own "protocol" - similar like HTTP, FTP, etc.

Comment: I think you don't need pickle to send data - pickle convert object into bytes to sent it but probaby PyGame can give you image as bytes or string.

Comment: Thank you very much for all theses informations. I will try this as soon as possible :)
And, i've just founded that pygame image to string is possible.

Comment: Now i did a program wich send 2048 by 2048, but ~112 time 2048, it don't send 2048, it LOSE? some packets.
So, i putted a print into the sender. And, i've founded the problem : The sender. because the receiver received 2048 OK, but the sender cannot send 2048 ? why ? 
so i downgraded to 1024, and it's the same, but at ~224 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made example which sends surface with current time.

(Pygame can't work with my camera).

It uses `struc.pack()` to send image size always as 4 bytes before image is send. So client first receives 4 bytes and have image size. Then it can use this information to receive image.

Both use loops to send/receive all the time.

**server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame
from threading import Thread
import socket
import struct # to send `int` as  `4 bytes`
import time   # for test

# --- constants ---

ADDRESS = ("localhost", 12801)

SURFACE_SIZE = (640, 480)

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)

# --- classes ---

class Streaming(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

        pygame.init()

        #pygame.camera.init()
        #self.cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0", SURFACE_SIZE)
        #self.cam.start()

        # create surface to imitate camera image
        self.image = pygame.Surface(SURFACE_SIZE)
        self.image_rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # create font to display text on surface
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)

    def get_image(self):
        # emulate cam.get_image()

        # get current time as string
        current_time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%s')

        # render surface with text (and center it)
        text = self.font.render(current_time, True, BLACK, GREEN)
        text_rect = text.get_rect(center=self.image_rect.center)

        # clear image and put new text
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.blit(text, text_rect)

        return self.image

    def run(self):

        s = socket.socket()

        # solution for: "socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use"
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        s.bind(ADDRESS)
        s.listen(1)

        print("Wait for connection")

        try:
            sc, info = s.accept()
            print("Video client connected:", info)

            while True:
                # get image surface

                #image = self.cam.get_image()
                image = self.get_image()

                # convert surface to string

                img_str = pygame.image.tostring(image, 'RGB')

                print('len:', len(img_str))

                # send string size

                len_str = struct.pack('!i', len(img_str))
                sc.send(len_str)

                # send string image

                sc.send(img_str)

                # wait

                time.sleep(0.5)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            # exit
            print("Closing socket and exit")
            sc.close()
            s.close()
            pygame.quit()

# --- main ---

Streaming().run()
```

**client.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame
from threading import Thread
import socket
import struct

# --- constants ---

ADDRESS = ("localhost", 12801)

SURFACE_SIZE = (640, 480)

# --- classes ---

class Receiving(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def run(self):
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect(ADDRESS)

        try:
            running = True
            while running:
                # receive size

                len_str = s.recv(4)
                size = struct.unpack('!i', len_str)[0]

                print('size:', size)

                # receive string

                img_str = b''

                while size > 0:
                    if size >= 4096:
                        data = s.recv(4096)
                    else:
                        data = s.recv(size)

                    if not data:
                        break

                    size -= len(data)
                    img_str += data

                print('len:', len(img_str))

                # convert string to surface

                image = pygame.image.fromstring(img_str, SURFACE_SIZE, 'RGB')
                image_rect = image.get_rect(center=self.screen_rect.center)

                # blit

                self.screen.blit(image, image_rect)
                pygame.display.flip()

                #self.clock.tick(30)

                # wait for ESC or close window

                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        running = False
                    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                            running = False

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            # exit
            print("Closing socket and exit")
            s.close()
            pygame.quit()

# --- main ---

Receiving().run()
```

Comment: Thank You.
I've tryed, and it look like a good solution, but in the loop of receiving, it receive well, but at the last time, it wait at the infinite. because it's writed recv(4096), but the server finished sending

Comment: in normal situation when server `close()` socket then `recv()` stops waiting. I don't remember if there is some `EOF` char (End Of File) which inform that it is end of data. But you can first send information how many data will be send so then you know how many times use `recv()`. I try to do example.

Comment: I put new code in answer. Now it use loop to send/receive image all the time. It sends image with current time. Server always send 4 bytes with image size before it sends image, and client alway receive 4 bytes before it start receive image - so it know how many bytes it has to receive.

Comment: Thank you very much !!
You program is working well, but now, i think because of too many bytes, when i try to do it with an image of the camera, it say : `String length does not equal format and resolution size`
when i try to import the image from string `image = pygame.image.fromstring(img_str, SURFACE_SIZE, 'RGB')`
But the `size` is really equal to 0, and the `len(img_str)` is also equals to the good amount..

Comment: It can means that `img_str` is too short (or too long) to create image with size `SURFACE_SIZE`. Is `SURFACE_SIZE` a size of oryginal image from camera ? Or maybe connection losts some data.

Comment: I've calculated the md5 of `img_str` in both client and server. It's the same, so connection do not lost data. Now, i need to try to get the size of the original image from the camera.

Comment: camer gives you `image` which is `pygame.Surface` so it should work `image.get_rect().width`, `image.get_rect().height`. Or maybe even `image.get_width()`, `image.get_height()`

Comment: Hey ! Thank you very much :=)
Now it's working totally well !
My camera accly taked a photo of (640, 480) when i putted (680, 480), so, the image was too short. I updated the variable of the surface : `SURFACE_SIZE` to this size, and now, it's working perfectly !
Thank again, you really helped me, and anyone who want to transfer usb video (or image) over network in python :)
You maybe can juste update this in the code ( (640, 480) ), because it's maybe the same for all camera. I got the camera image size with camera.get_rect() and printing this.

Comment: Hey we added the comment in the same time hehe, now it's ok :)

Comment: :) I changed `680` to `640`. `640x480` is standard resolution so `680x480` was strange.

Comment: Yeah, i didn't thinked to this resolution hehe. I juste putted in it.